# Where is a celebration-free, little-to-no Christmas skiing destination during the holiday season?

Tags: air-travel, public-holidays, skiing, christmas

I'm trying to plan a skiing trip for Christmas holidays which is when I can use my work holidays, however I do not celebrate Christmas and I do not enjoy the whole consumerist/festive/you-name-it Christmas vibe. Checking a few resorts and packages in the Alps, it seems like they're all going to have massive huge celebrations in the mountains! So I'm considering going somewhere different where xmas isn't too big.

- Iran isn't an option for this trip as it's on the agenda for the next year
- Morocco seems to have snow at that time of the year, but I'm not sure what the resorts are like
- Russia is said to be hit and miss for skiing
- Flights to Uzbekistan are horrendously expensive
- Georgia is also similar to Uzbekistan (but less expensive) and since the lifts incident there last year I'm a bit skeptical about going there
- Turkey is probably one option, but I'd like to know if there are other destinations that I could consider, that would have affordable flights from Europe (no more than a few hundred Euro)?

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question.  Identifying destinations that meet certain criteria is not the same thing as constructing a travel itinerary.

Comment: @phoog Maybe. But is this not the type of question that attracts list-type answers?

Comment: @JoErNanO You're the boss, but I don't think it's off-topic to get information on destinations with certain criteria, it helps everyone to have an idea of the topic. I could edit the title to remove the price section out of it if that can improve the post?

Comment: Here you call Christmas having a consumerist vibe, but in the comments on one of the answers you talk about Christmas as being the Christian celebration. Those two are different events (the first one is about a dude in a red robe and a Coca Cola bottle, the second one about celebrating, off date, the birth of Jesus 2000+ years ago in September). Which one do you want to avoid?

Comment: Is it only mountain skiing you are interested in or distance too? Quite a different set of locations available then.

Comment: @Gnudiff I should have mentioned I’m only intermediate and I still don’t know cross-country or touring, so downhill and lifts it is for me till I improve some more and maybe make more snow friends to go with

Comment: Where will you be leaving from? That can greatly affect the price of flights...

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey Dublin, Ireland

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a list question which may end up with many equal correct answers.

Comment: @CGCampbell I understand and respect your point, but Earth is one, and the non-Catholic/Protestant/Gregorian skiing areas on it are limited, so it's unlikely to have many answers populated for this. Why not have a reference on the site here for future as well?

Comment: @Neeku I'm not the boss. I'm just venting my opinion. The fact that you added a bullet list of destinations that may or may not be suitable, based on several unpredictable and/or opinion based criteria suggests that this question is likely to attract a list of equally right and wrong answers. Therefore it is my opinion that this question is off topic as per our rules. Have a read on our [help] to gain a better understanding on how SE works.

Comment: @Neeku You have not answered the question from Hans Janssen, though you later comment to CGCampbell that "the non-Catholic/Protestant/Gregorian skiing areas on it are limited." Is it safe to say then that you want to avoid not only the consumerism but also the religious activities? Your question made it sound like you just wanted to avoid the gift-giving, tree-raising, ornamental, secular stuff that is these days celebrated instead of actual Christmas.

Comment: @JoErNanO: Apparently it isn't...

Comment: How about North Korea? It has ski resorts, a good climate for snow, and dislikes (or at least claims to) consumerism. Human rights or risk of arbitrary arrest aren’t listed in your criteria.

Comment: I believe even South Korea has ski resorts. It's more Christian than Japan or China but it's not going to be like Christmas in a typical western country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OTT to say they will all have massive huge celebrations. Russia may have a lot of -20'C at that time. Serbia may have small snowfall till January as it's southerly.

If you check the events time-table of the stations from their website, and research photos/videos for "skitown noel/christmas 2018" to see the atmosphere, and see if they have a swimming resort for the kids if the weather is bad.

The ski-conoisseurs of the alps worry about snow depth at Christmas time, which is often not enough at lower altitudes, so wherever you go, make sure that it will have snowed enough by then. North of the Alps should be cooler for snow.

Yes, Nearly all european stations will have an event on Christmas day and some street decorations for a couple of weeks, and New-Year fireworks. Some stations only have a single day of events on the 25th called "christmas celebrations" and "new year fireworks" which is only one day of celebrations.

Here is a list of small french stations advised to avoid industrial atmosphere and chrismas celebrations, you can translate it to english, and probaby find similar discussions for Austria and the Baltic states.

https://www.skipass.com/forums/enmontagne/stations_ski_france/sujet-142512.html

Answer (score 48):

Well, Serbia and other countries that still use the Juliane calender celebrate Christmas on 7th of January, so that could be an option. In Serbia there is the Kopaonik ski resort that is really good and has plentiful snow that time of the year. Good luck

Comment: Bosnia/Serb Republic also have beautiful mountains and low cost flights, but I'm not sure if there's any skiing infrastructure.

Comment: Jahorina ski resort in Bosnia is one of the biggest in east Europe and even hosted the Winter Olympics. And as I said, Kopaonik in Serbia is a great resort.

Comment: Armenia has both good [ski infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsaghkadzor_ski_resort) and [recently-opened Ryanair routes](https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/ryanairs-low-fares-come-to-armenia/).

Comment: interesting that the answer about Israel has 3 downvotes and a negative comment with 2 upvotes for political reason, but not a peep about the Serbia answer.  I wonder why that is

Answer (score 44):

Japan?

- Pretty cheap to fly to from anywhere in the world.
- Fairly standard western country prices once you get there (certainly less than the Alps!)
- Very good ski facilities and ski-worthy weather.
- Christmas isn't particularly celebrated beyond a bit of themed advertising in shops. Christmas is a
  normal work day for most people.
- Japan in general is awesome.

Comment: @stbr No location was given in the question or tagged so it should be treated as a general travel question.

Comment: @pboss3010 She didn't write down her location but she proposed only destination in Europe / or close to (aka Morocco), this must be a hint, otherwise she would have probably thought about South America I think..

Comment: @pboss3010 Location is given in the last line of the question:*"[destinations] that would have affordable flights from **Europe** (no more than a few hundred Euro)?"*

Comment: The idea that Japan is "pretty cheap to fly to from anywhere in the world" is certainly news to me.

Comment: In any case Japan wouldn't be a good choice. Christmas is a huge date night there.

Comment: @ChrisH Didn't you know that the US is the center of the world :D ? Joke appart, the minimum price for a round trip flight from Dublin to Tokyo is about 750€ when it is 200€ from Dublin to Lyon - Zurich - Geneve. And we all know it's nice to take a 20h flight when she would already be skiing in Europe meanwhile she would still be in the plane to Japan.

Comment: The question mentioned Uzbekistan, so no mention of Europe only.  The question also said they want to avoid xmas. So, the catholic/protestant parts of europe are out and I personally have never been to Russia, Georgia or other potential eastern places.

Japan is actually a pretty cheap place to fly to. Loads of flights into Tokyo every day. 500 euros return at a max.

Christmas as a date night in Japan- only in anime. In reality most regard it as little more than another day.

Comment: @theotherone Searching kayak for flexible dates on the week around Christmas from any of London/Paris/Amsterdam to any of the Tokyo airports, the cheapest return ticket is 640 euros, typical prices are closer to 1000. To Osaka, cheapest is 680, typical prices more like 850-1000. Now, I can believe you might be able to save a bit more if you look a little longer, but "500 euros return at a max" is absolute nonsense.

Comment: Christmas may be just a date, but New Years just a few days later is a huge deal. The prices, transportation and just general nuisance that comes with holidays is still very much present due to preemptiveness for these dates. Also they might not be religious about it, but Christmas is still an imported festivity with the whole Santa and KFC and Cake thing they have going on which OP doesn't want.

Comment: @theotherone How can you compare Uzbekistan to Japan from Europe, Japan is over 2 times more far away, increasing the transportation time by at least 3 times (because you can probably not do it in one step) + the jet lag. I don't think you actually realize the distance between Western Europe and Japan for just a skiing trip of 1 week. Definitely makes no sense. And no it does NOT cost 500€ any day during this period. Unless you can prove it, but according to what I found it's at least 200-300€ over what you say.

Comment: I lived in Japan for 3 years. KFC and christmas cake are things, but not particularly culturally dominant. Christmas in Japan is less obtrusive than halloween in the UK was a few decades ago (before it became super americanised).   Japan is far more convenient from Europe than Uzbekistan- its a single flight on a very popular route rather than being an out of the way place it can be hard to get to and probably requires several transfers.   Absoutely nothing was mentioned about Ireland in the OP. For her specific situation maybe Serbia is better. But more generally Japan is a good option

Comment: @stbr The only skiing in South America at Christmastime is going to be water-skiing. The temperature averages around 32°C.

Comment: Japan is less (commercial) Christmas-y, but it's not nothing. It has been increasing, especially over the past ~10 years (same as Halloween). Of course, there is more in the large cities, but I have seen a Christmas display in the front window of a 7-11 in Kofu (!). It's (hopefully) much less at the ski resorts, but I haven't visited them.

Comment: @shoover: the temperature "averages 32C"? Even if true, which I don't think for a minute it is, are you aware that South America is twice the size of the USA? And that Ushuaia and Caracas are much much further apart than north Alaska  and San Diego? And, by the way, the average temperature for January in Ushuaia is 9C.

Comment: @stbr, I took a bus from Burgos to London for €109—I’d consider the convenience of flying not worth €100 more.  What does RyanAir charge?  (Not that I’d ever fly with them!)

Comment: @stbr to be fair, we prefer a question that can apply to everyone and helps more than only the OP, so it's better to generalize the question (as seen by the edited title by the mod) and let the reader (yes, everyone in the future) decides which location is better for them. Also, this question is currently on Hot Network Questions that is shown on the right sidebar of all SE sites, so skewed voting due to bias (and other things) is considered normal.

Comment: @pboss3010: A "date night" would typically not involve going on a ski trip.

Comment: Check the actual flights. I've definitely had cheap flights between Japan and other countries on routes that are not cheap year-round / all airlines.

Answer (score 13):

Pakistan.

It has one of the most beautiful and scenic skiing slopes in the world. Malam Jabba and Naltar to name a couple.

There are no Christmas based festivities either.

Your flight might be costly but that’s just about it. Rest of the stuff isn’t costly.

**Malam Jabba**

[image]
Courtesy: [dawn.com](https://i.dawn.com/primary/2017/02/58a7423ec5e77.jpg)

**Naltar**

[image]

Courtesy: [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Naltar_Slopy_Lands.jpg)

Google for Shimshal, Rattu, Nathia Gali, Astore and you will have numerous options.

[Good Read](https://www.talashme.com/skiing-in-pakistan/)

Answer (score 8):

In general, you cannot find such thing.

Christmas is a massive holidays around the world, often with holidays from schools, so you have many tourists that go around the world in such period, so nearly everywhere you will find price hike. This is independent if in the destination Christmas is celebrated or not.  The same for flights (but here if you add few extra days, on both end, you can get easily the cheap prices).

I assume you are looking ski holidays in Christmas period for the same reason: you (like many people) have free days on such period.

I recommend you to work as much as possible on such period, and do holidays in January (if possible, no kids): you will find good place to ski (because they need to prepare all slopes for Christmas, and be ready for the February holiday period). In such period you have much cheaper holidays (in general, not only on sky regions), but on ski regions you have very very few tourists [but on week ends].

Comment: Another issue is that a skiing destination is bound to have tourists. And lot of people in countries that celebrate holidays/gregorian calendar New Year will have days off, and some of them will want to go skiing. And the business at the location may chose to "celebrate" Christmas as a way to attract more of those tourists, even if it is not a local tradition.

Comment: "In general, you cannot find such thing.": I can. The places I and the other two answerers have mentioned are some of the spots that don't celebrate xmas. Remember that xmas is a Christian and Western thing and not all the world population fall into that category; those using other calendars than the Gregorian one, don't necessarily celebrate xmas. I am in fact planning to escape well before and after the peak season, and top of a mountain could be one of the best places to run away from xmas consumerism madness.

Comment: @Neeku: no, Serbia does not celebrate xmas like western Europe, but many Serbian in western Europe will fly home during western xmas. Ski destinations are mostly used by non-local people (during high season). To Japan: I see on Google flights that the flights are 70% (or more) more expensive than outside western xmas period, so the other answers didn't find the "cheap" part of your question.

Comment: Begin of january still a bit of high season. Best is end of january - beginning of february until the week BEFORE Valentines.

Comment: Downvoted: in Russia the week of December 25th is pretty quiet. Everyone's preparing for the New Year celebrations (which is the biggest holiday in Russia), so there might be a lot of people in shops buying gifts etc., but otherwise it's a normal working week. Also due to visa requirements, there're not a lot of tourists from Western countries. There're also several skiing regions in Russia (although as OP mentions the reviews are mixed).

Comment: Christmas is not a holiday in every country, for example Israel

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev: I just checked, flight to Sochi during xmas are much more expensive. OTOH also with the double price on xmas, the flight is very very cheap. As I wrote, it is not about places that do not celebrate xmas, but about millions of people having holidays in the same two weeks. The OP want to go cheap away from Eurozone on one of busiest periods for airports. But yeah, Russia could be a good option (but I'm not sure Russia is a cheap country [touristic places])

Answer (score 4):

You could try Russia. There are [several Ski Resorts](https://www.skiresort.info/ski-resorts/russia/). The week of 25th December is very quiet as Christmas is celebrated on 7th January.

Answer (score -4):

Israel has the Mount Hermon ski area.  I would expect you wouldn't find much in the way of Christmas observance there.

Comment: I don't know about the Mount Hermon area in particular, but Christmas is absolutely *huge* in Israel -- not so much locals celebrating, but tourists packing the place.

Comment: In addition to Mark's comment, Israel has only a single ski mountain and when it is snow-covered, it is absolutely packed. As much as I recommend traveling to Israel for culture, hikes, beach, resorts, and religious holidays, I do not recommend Israel for skiing.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Reported this comment: Brings politics into a travel-related question... "don't support the occupation" could be applied to virtually every answer on this site.  Every country is "occupying" something according to somebody

Of course some people only bring this up with a "certain country" for a "certain reason"

Comment: @Mark I don't know where you're seeing that but I have been around Israel a lot and have not seen hardly any signs of Christmas.  If a tourist area celebrated Christmas it would seriously turn off most of the local tourists, so I doubt they would do that.